# OCaml - Error while adding a parametrized function into a module

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I would like to extend this given definition:

```
module type StateChart = sig
    type 'a t
    val get : 'a t -> 'a
    val create : 'a -> 'a t
end


module ConcreteStateChart : StateChart = struct
    type 'a t = { state : 'a } (* internal configuration and current state expressed as 'a parameter *)
    let get m = m.state;;   (* obtaining the internal value *) 
    let create x = { state = x };;
end
```

into two modules where any kind of transaction of type `k` could be performed. I tried to define the following code, but:

```
module type StateChart = sig
    type 'a t
    type k
    val get : 'a t -> 'a
    val create : 'a -> 'a t
    val transaction : 'a t -> k -> 'a t
end


module ConcreteStateChart : StateChart = struct
    type 'a t = { state : 'a } (* internal configuration and current state expressed as 'a parameter *)
    type k = 'a option
    let get m = m.state;;   (* obtaining the internal value *) 
    let create x = { state = x };;
    let transaction x y = (* Stupid StateChart that changes the state dependingly to an option parameter *)
        match y with
        | Some z -> { state = z}
        | None -> x;;   
end
```

it seems that the k definition doesn't remember the **'a** binding performed in *'a t*:

> type k = **'a** option;;
>
> Error: Unbound type parameter **'a**

How could I define such a *transaction* that could be laterly implemented in a *ConcreteStateChart* Module?

Answer (score 1):

The type variables appear in the right hand side of data type definition must be quantified: `k` should be defined as with an type parameter:

```
type 'a k = 'a option
```

What you want to express, `k` must be an option of the content type of `t`, cannot be expressed in the level of data type definitions, but in the uses of them at `transaction`:

```
val transaction : 'a t -> 'a k -> 'a t
```

, which means the content types of `t` and `k` must be the same.

Comment: Well, when I express monads in OCaml I use the following definition, which is admitted by the compiler: val bind: 'a t -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'b t . This means that, if t is list, I could indeed write a let bind m f = List.concat (List.map f m)

Comment: I do not understand your comment.  Anything with the error of `type k = 'a option`? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry. So there is no way to make the k type dependant from the `'a` type parameter (which is by the way accepted on the `'a t` definition?) For me even a definition like the following one could be appealing: `type k = 'a`.